# Plotting a line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line graph using ggplot2 on R.3.0.2 with the below data and code but it returns an error of `geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` without any output. How can I solve this i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302070/bar-and-line-plot-in-one-chart-with-a-legend-under-ggplot2)

```
month <- c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08" ,"09","10", "11" ,"12",NA)
yr.count <- c(357.500000 ,301.785714, 317.142857 ,283.071429 ,332.500000 ,333.285714 ,354.285714, 308.357143 ,272.142857 ,273.214286, 312.571429 ,337.714286,5.92857)
month.mean2 <- data.frame(month=month, yr.count=yr.count)
ggplot() + geom_line(data=month.mean2, 
                     aes(x=month, y=as.numeric(yr.count)), 
                     colour='red')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, using characters on an axis implies that there are multiple values for each unique value, and that some kind of aggregation needs to take place. You can force the lines to be connected by setting `group = 1`:

```
month <- c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08" ,"09","10", "11" ,"12",NA)
yr.count <- c(357.500000 ,301.785714, 317.142857 ,283.071429 ,332.500000 ,333.285714 ,354.285714, 308.357143 ,272.142857 ,273.214286, 312.571429 ,337.714286,5.92857)
month.mean2 <- data.frame(month=month, yr.count=yr.count)
ggplot() + geom_line(data=month.mean2, 
                     aes(x=month, y=as.numeric(yr.count), group = 1), 
                     colour='red')
```

[image]